# apex oracle validation solution

Tags: oracle, validation, plsql, oracle-apex

I need 3 validations for my apex oracle database application and can't seem to find the solution.

- validation so that the field cannot be Null
- Validation so that the number entered must be between 1 and 1000
- Validation so that the date of birth cannot be after `5/6/2018`  (`dd // mm / yyyy` format)

These validations are used in the form using CREATE VALIDATION in the edit page

Comment: Are you want to validate this at the database level with the table? i.e. inside CREATE TABLE statement??

Comment: Do you want to add all these 3 validations over the same field, I think not, might be in two different fields. So can you also update the table structure that you still tried out?

Comment: These validations are used in the forms using CREATE VALIDATION in the edit page and they are used for three different fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new Validation with type PL/SQL Function (returning Error Text) with code:

```
if :P1_ITEM1 is null then return 
'P1_ITEM1 is null' end if; 

if :P1_ITEM2 not between 1 and 1000 then return 
'P1_ITEM2 not between' end if; 

if to_date(:P1_ITEM3, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= to_date('05/10/2000') then return 
'P1_ITEM3 earlier than 05/06/2018' end if; 

return null;
```

Additionally in Error Message type:

```
Unknown error.
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

- create a validation by right-clicking the item, and choose its type to be `item is NOT NULL`.

  - alternatively, set item's "Value required" property to "Yes".
- that item is a "Numeric field", so - set its "Minimum" and "Maximum value" properties to desired values
- date of birth looks like a SYSDATE (i.e. today's date). If that's so, set its "Maximum value" to `+0d`

  - `+` as to "future"
  - `0` as "zero"
  - `d` as "days"

Comment: Though, you could create validation as a PL/SQL function which returns *Error Text" (if that's what you prefer).